# two elements are fired while only one needs to be fired

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

```
<div class="subitems">
  <ul>
      <li id="China"></li> 
         <li id="India">
       India
       <div id="subitems">
         <ul>
            <li id="India/Sub Item 1">Sub Item 1</li>
            <li id="India/Sub Item 2">Sub Item 2</li>
            <li id="India/Sub Item 3">Sub Item 3</li>
            <li class="additem">+</li>
         </ul>
           </div>
         </li>
       <li>id="Austria"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Like you would expect with this code:

```
$('.subitems ul li').mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        alert('right mouse clicked');
    }
});
```

is that when `India/SubItem1` is clicked, both the India `<li>` and the `India/SubItem1` `<li>` are fired, while I only want `India/SubItem1` to be fired. And when India is clicked I only want india to fire.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation();` will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM:

```
$('.subitems ul li').mousedown(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.which == 3) {
        alert('right mouse clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, there is no way in hell I would've thought of that or be able to google it :)